# How do I take a mysql query and print the results on a cakephp page

Tags: mysql, cakephp, controllers

With links to each user.

For example. "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE rating > 50" this query yields 120 results... how to print those results on a page in order of rating with links to each profile..

a leaderboard if you will

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start would be to review the docs at http://book.cakephp.org/ but in short it will follow Cake's MVC principles. You'll need a model to interact with the database and pass this data back to a controller.  The controller will then pass that information to the relevant view script and which point you can layout the recordset as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read up on CakePHP like @simnom has suggested. Once you do, your query and view code should look something like this:

Users Controller:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('order'=> array('User.rating' => 'desc'), 'conditions'=>array('User.rating >' => '50')));
$this->set('users', $users);
```

View Code:

```
<?php
foreach ($users as $user):
   echo $this->Html->link("View User", array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $user['id']));
endforeach;
?>
```